# Cannot access Spotify through squid proxy

Tags: proxy, squid, spotify

I setup a personal squid proxy without authentication so i could connect to spotify. I can connect to normal websites and i acan also connect to Spotify website however i cant connect to Spotify using the desktop client.

Im - using CentOS8 on a VM instance running on Google Cloud

This is what i got from the Squid logs:

```
1583232708.738      0 175.157.46.53 TCP_DENIED/403 3835 CONNECT gae2-accesspoint-b-61fn.ap.spotify.com:4070 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1583232710.978      0 175.157.46.53 TCP_DENIED/403 3835 CONNECT gae2-accesspoint-b-0j8r.ap.spotify.com:4070 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1583232812.108      0 175.157.46.53 TCP_DENIED/403 3835 CONNECT gae2-accesspoint-b-kdh7.ap.spotify.com:4070 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1583232815.938      0 175.157.46.53 TCP_DENIED/403 3835 CONNECT gae2-accesspoint-b-x11x.ap.spotify.com:4070 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1583233583.698      0 175.157.46.53 TCP_DENIED/403 3829 CONNECT gae2-accesspoint-b-pnz9.ap.spotify.com:80 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1583233587.078      0 175.157.46.53 TCP_DENIED/403 3835 CONNECT gae2-accesspoint-b-88vj.ap.spotify.com:4070 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1583233777.928      0 175.157.46.53 TCP_DENIED/403 3835 CONNECT gae2-accesspoint-b-xb9m.ap.spotify.com:4070 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1583233780.328      0 175.157.46.53 TCP_DENIED/403 3835 CONNECT gae2-accesspoint-b-36xp.ap.spotify.com:4070 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1583233927.019      0 175.157.46.53 TCP_DENIED/403 3835 CONNECT gae2-accesspoint-b-4s3h.ap.spotify.com:4070 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1583233931.059      0 175.157.46.53 TCP_DENIED/403 3835 CONNECT gae2-accesspoint-b-rq9g.ap.spotify.com:4070 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
```

My squid configuration:

```
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
acl localnet src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255  # RFC 1122 "this" network (LAN)
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8             # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10          # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
acl localnet src 169.254.0.0/16         # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12          # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16         # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src fc00::/7               # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10              # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl Safe_ports port 4070        #Spotify
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this with the same problem. But then I just tried to add 4070 to SSL_ports as well and it worked. It needs both acl entries:

```
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl SSL_ports port 4070     # spotify
acl SSL_ports port 8443     # openshift port

acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl Safe_ports port 4070    # spotify
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
```

Comment: can i get your entire spotify config?